# How do I make my certificate work on Safari

Tags: azure-web-app-service, certificate

I am using Azure web app and I have a domain certified from Google Domain. It's a GeoTrust Global TLS.
Everything works fine with all browsers except on Safari (Mac or IPhone). It shows the website is not secure. I will work after you refresh the page on Mac then no problems anymore. Refreshing doesn't solve it on IPhones.

When I run the [Qualys](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=breftech.com) it shows two certificates actually, one from the website and one from azurewebsites.net

I am not sure if someone had the same issue in the past and can recommend a way for Safari to show secure right away.

Thank you,
Bilel

Comment: This isn't programming or development, but the second cert/chain shown by Qualys is for "No SNI" -- because azure hosts lots and lots of websites, probably thousands on each machine, and without SNI it can't use a site-specific cert. Safari _should_ be sending SNI [unless your iPhone is really ancient](https://caniuse.com/sni) or it's actually going through a proxy gateway portal or such. Are you using phone-data or wifi or bluetooth, and if the latter is the Mac also using that? If you try http(no-S) do you get your site or something else?

Comment: I just realized that sending the whole https://site resolves it. I guess typing site alone makes it hard for Safari to identity the right certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that sending the whole https://site resolves it. I guess typing site alone makes it hard for Safari to identity the right certificate.